# Can a more electropositive metal replaced by a less electropositive one?

Tags: redox, metal, elements, electronegativity, reduction-potential

I read from [this reference](http://www.elementsdatabase.com/Rubidium-Rb-37-element/) that rubidium is extracted by reduction of its chloride with calcium or sodium. How is it possible?. Their electronegativities are much higher than rubidium. I think rubidium is far more reactive than either and can not be replaced from its salt by any other metal except cesium. While I have also read that cesium itself is replaced from its chloride by magnesium [refer to this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesium_chloride#Uses). How can a less electropositive metal replace a more electropositive metal from its salt? Are there some factors besides electronegativity, reduction potential and other reaction skills?

Comment: both reactions require extrernal source of heat. The process is actually an equilibrium, but at elevated temperatures rubidium and cesium relatively easily evaporate, which is used to shift the equilibrium.

Comment: But @permeakra how an equilibrium is established as extreme reactivity of such elements should not permit equilibrium at all. I think so

Comment: still, many processes are equilibriums. These ones included.

Comment: I tried to understand that @permeakra but I didn't even after much reading. Can you please explain it alongwith examples? I am not very good at chemistry.

Comment: And if equilibrium can be established between two metals wwith a considerable electronegativity difference then what's the use of electrolysis? Because almost every metal can be extracted by such equilibriums

Comment: While indeed equilibrium may be established for virtually all metals, it is still strongly shifted to more electronegative one. To shift it to less electronegative one, one have to be able to remove more electronegative one from the mixture. In the particular cases of cesium and rubidium it is achieved by vacuum distillation of the reaction mixture, because said metals vaporise relatively easily. That's not the case for most other metals.

Comment: @permeakra perhaps you meant to remove more electropositive?

Comment: yes, indeed more electropositive. To adress possible issue: quantum mechanincs states that every process is reversible, thus theoretically speking every reaction is reversible and it is possible to shift equilibrium in desirable direction. However, fragility of molecules involved or slow reaction rate often makes it impractical or plain impossible in realistic conditions.